# Making read from and write to databases

Tags: unity, networking, databases

I want to make a few simple databases for a sports game using Unity2D(C#).

One is a read-only google sheet where it takes the players from the pool and adds them into the game at the start.

Another one is a read and write database  where all 30 team's players will be saved as well as current stats( a lot of numbers), I don't know if i should make this online or local saves. I want to keep the cost at a minimal.

Generally new to making databases, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm sorry, but we require questions to describe a tangible problem. "Can someone point me in the right direction" is too vague, because it doesn't tell us what kind of help you really need.

Comment: If you question how do I create a database in Unity 2d (or persistent datastore which is more you need), that would be a better way to frame your question.  The other tip, if you have investigated anything in terms of libraries etc, then that also assist in showing what methods you have chosen.  And so, then helps those answering how to guide you to your desired goal.

Comment: Do you really need a database for this? If you want to use a google sheet as input, you can export it to a csv and read it into Unity as a TextAsset reasonably smoothly. For saving progress, a local save file might suffice if you want to keep complexity down (provided you're not worried about portability or cheating by modifying saves). Can you update your question to clarify whether a database is a hard requirement for this case?

Answer (score 1):

From past experience, I would say the easiest database system to manage would be SQLite. If you want to retain the data from your Google Sheet, you can convert them to a SQLite database with this extension for Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/convert-google-sheets-to/dhddhidmheohikpdhlhoefjkihdhngdh

You could make both into SQLite databases and then reference them from Unity. There are plently of tutorials out there to help you do this. To get started, use this one: https://answers.unity.com/questions/743400/database-sqlite-setup-for-unity.html

If you want the database to be server-side, it wouldn't be difficult to use Web-Sockets to query and add to the database. A node-js server is probably the best way to go about this. Hope this has answered your question.